Trying to attach a database gives Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)"
Trying to attach a database (SQL 2016), with the following command:
CREATE DATABASE [MYDB]
ON (FILENAME = 'E:\DBA\Data\MYDB_Data.mdf')
FOR ATTACH;

Renders the following error:
Msg 5120, Level 16, State 101, Line 4
Unable to open the physical file "E:\DBA\Data\MYDB_Data.mdf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)".
Msg 1802, Level 16, State 7, Line 4
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.

Others have suggested that permissions may be the issue. I don't see it in my case:
PS E:\DBA\Data> icacls .
. NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER:(F)
  BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)
  CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(F)
  BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(F)
  NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER:(OI)(CI)(F)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

PS E:\DBA\Data> icacls .\MYDB_Data.mdf
.\MYDB_Data.mdf BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)
                NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(F)
                NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER:(F)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

Service account is a domain account that is in the local Administrators group. Is there any hope for me?

If you can do connect with Win Auth. and Admin (or an account that has admin privileges) then repeat - attach db.

Problem could be solved with other user config - permission changes also.

This worked, but I had to use the sa account.
